# Why is declaring the object reference this way wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms, scope, declaration

I am trying to learn WinForms with C# and the code code section below works without error:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TempConversion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private RadioButton rdb;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            rdb = new RadioButton();
        }
        ...
```

But as shown below, if I declare **private RadioButton rdb** inside **public Form1()** then I get errors:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TempConversion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            private RadioButton rdb;
            rdb = new RadioButton();
        }
        ...
```

I could not figure out why the second case is wrong even though both declarations are inside the same namespace. What is the reason that in the second case **private RadioButton rdb** gives error when declared inside **public Form1()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# access modifiers (private, public, protected, etc) are only useful when used as a part of the class.  Inside of the constructor, or any other method they don't make any sense, because they are only visible inside of the method you are declaring the variable in.

So just get rid of the "private" keyword, and it will be fine.